# Why am I getting LoadError or NameError when trying to use HTTParty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, httparty

I'm trying to use the HTTParty gem as a part of the gem that I am creating; however I keep getting an uninitialized constant NameError or 'require': cannot load such file -- httparty LoadError. My class starts like this:

```
module Reporting
  class GitlabIssue
    include HTTParty
...
```

Leaving this at it is, I receive the following error:

> uninitialized constant Reporting::GitlabIssue::HTTParty (NameError)

Various searches turned up the solution for this is to require 'httparty' before the class block is opened. So I put the following at the top of my file:

```
require "httparty"
```

With that in place, I receive this error:

> 'require': cannot load such file -- httparty (LoadError)

My gemspec has the seemingly correct command to use the gem:

```
spec.add_dependency "httparty"
```

and when I do a bundle update/install, it lists the httparty gem as being installed and at version 0.13.3

When I load up an irb session, I can successfully require 'httparty' and it returns true without any errors. Any ideas what could be going on here?

Some system info: I'm running ruby 2.1.0p0 [x86_64-linux] and Rails 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with the order that your files (and HTTParty) are loaded in your gem. If you have the standard directory layout for your gem try this:

In your_app.gemspec ->

```
spec.add_dependency 'httparty'
```

At the top of your_app/lib/your_app.rb ->

```
require 'httparty'
```

Comment: This gets me the same error as above (cannot load such file -- httparty...) when I put it at the top of my file.

Answer (score 0):

I just runned in the exact same issue [here](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/386).

Turns out I included `HTTPParty` instead of `HTTParty`